# Uploading a zip folder to cloud storage

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, zip

Here's the scenario.

User uploads a zip file from a form. On the backend, I get the ZipInputStream and convert the inputstream to bytes and upload to GCS

```
`public String upload(
      String bucketName,
      String objectName,
      String contentType,
      InputStream objectInputStream)
      throws IOException {
    if (contentType == null) contentType = ContentType.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8;

    BlobId blobId;
    if (largeFile) {
      blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
      BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(contentType).build();
      WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo);
      if (storage.get(blobId) != null) writer = storage.update(blobInfo).writer();

      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int limit;
      while ((limit = objectInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        try {
          writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, limit));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Exception uploadObject", e);
        }
      }
      writer.close();
    } else {
      byte[] objectBytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(objectInputStream);
      blobId = storeByteArray(storage, bucketName, objectName, contentType, objectBytes);
      if (Objects.isNull(blobId)) return null;
    }
    return url(bucketName, objectName);
  }`
```

COde that gets the filepart and calls the above method

```
ZipInputStream filePartInputStream = new ZipInputStream(filePart.getInputStream());
storageGateway.uploadObject(
          "bucket_name",
          "objectname",
          filePart.getContentType(),
          filePartInputStream
       );
```

The upload works as expected but when I download the zip folder from GCS bucket, it seems to be corrupted. I was not able to unzip it.

Am I missing anyhting here ? If not what's the correct way to upload a zip file to google cloud storage

Comment: What is content-encoding set on the uploaded object? One situation I've seen is that the client or library (or browser) auto-decodes based on this header. And (assuming you're running on a Linux machine locally) what is the output of running `file downloaded_file`?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I set the contentEncoding of the blob to "gzip" while uploading the file. But the outcome was the same. Locally i'm running this on a MAC.

Edit : I ran the command file file_name.zip. The output was file_name.zip: empty

Comment: If you're not going to unpack it on the fly, there's no need to use `ZipInputStream`, just pass the `filePart.getInputStream` to the `storageGateway`.

I don't remember the `ZipInputStream` API, but it is possible that your current solution is actually unpacking `zip` on-the-fly and you're writing not-a-zip file to the storage.

Comment: Note: The `content-encoding` for zip files is `application/zip` and not `gzip`.

Comment: @Valkyrie after uploading, are you able to download the file using `gsutil cp`, and get a complete zip file like you originally uploaded? That would tell you the upload worked successfully and it was your download path that's having problems.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I checked  by using `gsutil cp` The downloaded file was corrupted. 
I tried with multiple files it was still the same. I'm guessing I must be doing something wrong with the upload.

Comment: @xSAVIKx  That didn't help as well.

Comment: @JohnHanley Tried that but didn't seem to work

Comment: I just posted a note and not an answer so that you know the correct Content-Encoding to prevent a future problem.

Comment: @Valkyrie - what library are you using to upload the object? I haven't seen `storeByteArray` so I'm guessing it's your own code? If so, can you post the code?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz yes that's my own code. 
However, I got this working.

It worked for me when I converted the fileInptStream to a byteArray and converted the byteArray to a byteArrayInputStream as below : 
`byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(filePartInputStream)` and `ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)`

Comment: Hi @Valkyrie please, consider adding the solution you found as an answer, so the Community can find out that you fixed the issue and you can help future users that face the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki answer, based in the comment provided by @Valkyrie, informing what she did to fix it.

The solution is to convert the `fileInptStream` to a `byteArray` and then, convert the `byteArray` to a `byteArrayInputStream` as below :

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(filePartInputStream) 
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)
```

This way, once the file is downloaded after being uploaded to Cloud Storage, the file should not be corrupted.